# Search in PnP Modern Search/site search not working unless explicity RefinableStrin100:myquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnpjs, kql

I have a document library with two content types. One for the folders (document set) and one (document) for the documents itself.

The document CT inherits from the other CT two columns and is these two columns/managed properties that cause issues. All the columns used in the CT/documents are mapped to refinables in the search schema, and the two inherited columns is mapped to refinableString 100 and 101.

In the PnP Modern Search result webpart I set the query to:

```
{searchTerms} 

ContentTypeId:0x010100924787320BFFBE4D93AC11D22C9FB71F00F9A8780FAF5B4847861313EDC7504E4F
```

This will instantly give me a view of all the documents. The CT above is the document above.

I connect the PnP search box and the search query will work for all columns EXCEPT the two inherited columns. I also tried on the site search and got the same results.

For the sake of test I tried with one of the refinables:

```
RefinableString100:{searchTerms}
```

Which worked, but obviously it will destroy and limit the functionality and view.

I have tried:

```
{searchTerms} OR RefinableString100:{searchTerms}
```

and

```
{?{searchTerms} RefinableString100:{searchTerms} OR ContentTypeID:0x010100924787320BFFBE4D93AC11D22C9FB71F00F9A8780FAF5B4847861313EDC7504E4F -RefinableString100: }
```

without luck. Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is clear what the problem is. What are you trying to achieve and what results are you seeing? Perhaps an example showing a few items and what is returned, and what you expect to be returned...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can describe your problem in more detail (for example, bring a schematic diagram of the effect or some screenshots), so that we can clearly understand your needs and help you solve the problem better.